# In Asp.net MVC having issues when using session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, async-await

I am using asp.net mvc 4.7.2 application. I am having an issue when creating session. Below is the code and the steps.

```
 //Load Controller
        Public async Task<ActionResult> Load()
        {
           var check=new Data();
           var info =  await check.GetInfo();          
           userModel = Utility.CreateModelList(info);
           Session["data"] = userModel;
        }


//login controller

 public  ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userName = 
            System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("name").Value;                              
            return RedirectToAction("Load", "Data");
            
         }
        return View();
    }

    /// </summary>
    public void SignIn()
    {

        try
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           
            throw;

        }
    }
```

Step 1.  User sign in successfully on the first attempt and get to the method which calls another async await method and session gets populated. No issue at this point.

Step2. User sign out.
Step3. user sign in.  Now user gets back to sign page in circle. keep hitting SignIn Method and user always seeing the Login page. Never move go to the index method so user can be redirected to load controller as it happened in step 1.

--To narrow down, I removed the session from the Load Action, then I did not get the issue everything seems fine.  Adding back the session in load action I get the issue.

I am suspecting it has to do with the session but not sure what it could be. Maybe it is session but then why code runs fine for the first time when user sign in and get the issue in subsequent sign in?

I further tried the above steps but this time without the async await method but issue remained the same. So issue is all about the session. But I don't know why that is an issue and what could be the solution.

Comment: I think the issue is with our sign out method.

Comment: I checked the code and validated sign-off functionality I didn't seem to find an issue with that.